# Insert Item After x Number of Posts in a Sequence

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress query where I'm loading 30 posts at a time and after every 4th posts I want to inject an advertisement block.

This issue I'm facing is I only want the advertisement to be injected after the 4th post within a 10 post sequence.

The ad should be displayed after post 4, 14 and 24 in the loop.

I cannot use a simple if statement ( `if(x == 4 || x == 14 || x == 24) { // inset ad }` ) because the amount of posts in the loop and the position of the advertisement block may change from page to page.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: `MOD` the `countPostsPulled` by `10` and `if=4 then...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the rule is - divide `$x` by 10 and take a remainder. If remainder equals 4 - it's what you need.

And code for this is:

```
if ($x % 10 == 4) {
    // do stuff
}
```